# Update checkout summary on selecting shipping method

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento-2.1.3

I have moved the `summary` one step up in the `Magento 2` checkout. I would like to update the `summary` once i select a `shipping method`.

Does anyone has suggestions how to pull this off?

Answer (score 12):

You just need to add the following file to your theme on path:

> [theme]/Magento_Checkout/web/js/action/select-shipping-method.js

```
define(
[
    '../model/quote'
],
function (quote) {
    "use strict";
    return function (shippingMethod) {
        quote.shippingMethod(shippingMethod)
    }
}
);
```

will become:

```
define(
[
    '../model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information'
],
function (quote, setShippingAction) {
    "use strict";

    return function (shippingMethod) {
        quote.shippingMethod(shippingMethod);
        if (shippingMethod !== null) {
            //To update cart total after selecting shipping method.
            setShippingAction([]);
        }
    };
} 
);
```

Now it works!

Comment: It should selected as correct answer. Working like charm !! Thanks a lot

Comment: Simple and perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue in Magento 2.2.6 version.

I tried the **@chiriac** answer but it will stop the whole checkout process for guest users.

You can use as below:

```
define([
    '../model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/totals-processor/default'
], function (quote, totalsDefaultProvider) {
    'use strict';

    return function (shippingMethod) {
        console.log("select shipping methods");
        quote.shippingMethod(shippingMethod);
        totalsDefaultProvider.estimateTotals(quote.shippingAddress());

    };
});
```

Comment: you are talking about a code I have added in 2017 .... Jun 23 '17 at 17:45 ... more then 2.5 years ago ...